# How to send Japanese characters using HttpPost

Tags: android, unicode, encoding, character-encoding, http-post

I'm trying to send Japanese characters to my API server but the characters sent were garbled and became `????`. So I set the encoding to the entity using:

```
    StringEntity stringEntity = new StringEntity(message, "UTF-8");
```

but the output became `org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity@4316f850`. I wonder if converting the `stringEntity` to string caused this since I want to send it in my server as `String`.

Here's how I used it:

```
public static String postSendMessage(String path, String message) throws Exception {
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpClient.getParams(), 10000); // Timeout limit
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(SystemInfo.getApiUrl() + path);
    List<NameValuePair> value = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    StringEntity stringEntity = new StringEntity(message, "UTF-8");
    value.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", stringEntity.toString())); //Here's where I converted the stringEntity to string

    UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(value);
    httpPost.setEntity(entity);
    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
    InputStream is = httpEntity.getContent();

    String result = convertStreamToString(is);
    return result;
}
```

Where could I have gone wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to use `StringEntity`.

```
List<NameValuePair> value = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
value.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", message));
```

Instead, you have to pass a second argument for initializing `UrlEncodedFormEntity.

```
UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(value, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Thanks, my server has now accepted the characters. I have related question though, in my app I cannot download files with Japanese filenames, for example a PDF named - ははは.pdf. Is there some way to set also the encoding for download? [Here](http://pastebin.com/NSTycJeu)'s the code.

Comment: @CompaqLE2202x: you don't show where you are getting `url` or `pdfFilename` from, but in general `url` as a URI must be pure ASCII. If you have an IRI with non-ASCII characters in you will need to convert that to a URI first; for the path part that is done by %-encoding the UTF-8 bytes for the characters. `URLEncoder.encode(filename, "UTF-8")` nearly does that (except it gets spaces wrong, you can replace `+` with `%20` to fix that).

Comment: @bobince Actually `pdfFileName` is just the filename with extension, and the url is `path[0]`, for example (`http://192.168.xx.xx/resources/upload/pdf/ははは.pdf`). But when I pasted it in the browser, it became (`http://192.168.xx.xx/resources/upload/pdf/%E3%81%AF%E3%81%AF%E3%81%AF.pdf`). I converted `path[0]` to `URI` then to `URL` as you said but then nothing happened. I also tried `String urlEncoded = URLEncoder.encode(path[0], "UTF-8");` but triggered `Protocol not found`. Could you enlighten me more?